# How do I tell TypeScript that a function modifies values in its parent scope?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

So TypeScript under some circumstances will automatically reduce the type space of a value when inside an if statement. This is very useful. However I am frequently dealing with the issue that if a function is called that modifies the value it won't re widen the type space.

Here is a simplified example of the issue:

```
function example() {
    let val = "foo";
    function modifyVal() {
        val = "bar";
    }
    if(val == "foo") {
        //typescript knows that val must be the unit type "foo"
        modifyVal(); //this changes it's value 
        //typescript still thinks that val == "foo" and thinks it
        //shouldn't be comparable to "bar"  
        if(val == "bar") {

        }
    }
}
```

Is there some easy way to disable this feature? Or get the compiler to identify that `val` is modified. Currently I am using `val as T` whenever this comes up.

I am using version `2.7.0-dev.20171104`. However the behavior also shows up in the online Playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

**EDIT:** I just checked this is also an issue with classes and functions that modify their state.

Comment: Try this: `if(val == <string>"bar") { }`

Comment: This is known [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) in control flow analysis. You have several workarounds, but the most straightforward for now is just ignore it with `// @ts-ignore`

Comment: @AlekseyL. Thanks. I was looking for a github issue just couldn't find the correct thing to google. Interestingly that issue seems to use parsers as an example a lot. That is exactly what I am working on at the moment. 

This use-case is very uncommon thought and often state modifications like this decrease code readability so it's not actually that big of an issue the more I think about it.